# lexically scoped variable retains value after being overwritten in a getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, getjson, lexical

In the code at the end of this post, the variable `pPrice` is defined via 
`$(addProduct).attr(attrProductPrice);` and then set in a JSON call via
`$.getJSON(url, function(data) { console.log(data); pPrice = data.price; });`
but after the synchronous `.getJSON` call, the value has returned to its original value.

How can I overwrite the definition of the definition of the lexically scoped variable via the `.getJSON` call? Source code is abbreviated to relevant part:

```
  function addToCart(i,qty){
     var pPrice = $(addProduct).attr(attrProductPrice); //original value
     var url = '/pricefor/' + pId;
     $.getJSON(url, function(data) { console.log(data); pPrice = data.price; }); // new value
     console.log(pPrice); // new value lost! back to original value?!        
  }
```

Comment: Are you certain the ``$.getJSON`` call is really synchronous?  It's async by default unless you overrode the global jQuery AJAX settings somewhere else.  This should work otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getJSON` call is asynchronous.  Your function isn't invoked until the JSON is retrieved from the server.  The timeline looks like this:

```
var pPrice = $(addProduct).attr(attrProductPrice);
var url = '/pricefor/' + pId;
$.getJSON(url, blah blah);
console.log(pPrice);

# some time later, when the server responds, your function is called.
console.log(data); pPrice = data.price;
```